# Annotate a table to show increments between entries

Tags: tables

I am looking for a way to typeset a table with annotations showing the changes between successive entries.  The (sloppy, hand-made) image below shows what I have in mind. Notice that the added entries should appear "between" the entries of the table.  I don't particularly care whether the tables run horizontally, as shown, or vertically.

[image]

Ideally, whatever solution you can propose would be capable of being iterated, as shown in the next image:

[image]

I *don't* need the differences to be automatically calculated, and in fact I'd prefer it if they were not.

I hope what I'm asking for is clear.  I'll be happy to clarify.

**Edit:** The table that I want to markup is:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$x$&$0$&$3$&$6$&$9$&$12$&$15$&$18$&$21$&$24$\\
\hline
$f(x)$&$-20$&$-15$&$-8$&$1$&$12$&$25$&$40$&$57$&$76$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

but I don't know if that is particularly helpful, especially if (like @cfr in the comments) you can't see my images.

Comment: Perhaps what you want is more "visual" but, just a thought, why don't you consider including extra table lines for the differences using `multicolumn`?

Comment: @gusbrs It may be that I don't know enough about multicolumn. Can it be used to create cells that are offset halfway between columns?

Comment: Not exactly, it will create a single cell which encompasses the space of a number of cells, in your case, two. I can try to provide an example, if you think this might be an alternative for you.

Comment: @gusbrs I can see how that might work.  If you could provide an example I would appreciate it.

Comment: The thing is, you haven't provided any code to work with, so you're asking people to create an example from scratch. Your question should include code for a minimal document which people can modify to show you how to do what you want.

Comment: @cfr I'll be happy to provide a table showing the data I want to markup, but I don't have even the first clue how to code it so that the markup appears correctly.

Comment: I'd use a `matrix of nodes` in a Ti*k*Z picture and then annotate the nodes, which are then automatically named.

Comment: @cfr I really don't know how a matrix of nodes works, so if you could provide an example I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Ti*k*Z does have a manual, you know. With examples and stuff. There are also lots of examples here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `matrix of math nodes` using Ti*k*Z. I use loops to save typing but these are not, of course, mandatory.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [inner sep=0pt, draw=gray!75!blue, thick, matrix of math nodes, nodes={inner sep=2.5pt, text width=20pt, align=center}, column 1/.append style={nodes={align=right, text width=25pt}}]
  {
     \strut x&0&3&6&9&12&15&18&21&24\\
     \strut f(x)&-20&-15&-8&1&12&25&40&57&76\\
  };
  \draw [gray!75!blue, semithick] (m.west |- m-1-1.south) -- (m.east |- m-1-1.south) \foreach \i in {1,...,9} { (m.north -| m-1-\i.east) -- (m.south -| m-1-\i.east) };
  \foreach \i [count=\k from 1, count=\j from 3, remember=\j as \jlast (initially 2)] in {5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19}
  \draw [thick, draw=blue!50!cyan]
    ([xshift=1.5pt, yshift=.5pt]m-2-\jlast.south) -- ([yshift=-7.5pt]m-2-\jlast.south east) node (d\k) [below] {$\i$} -- ([xshift=-1.5pt, yshift=.5pt]m-2-\j.south)
    ([xshift=1.5pt, yshift=-.5pt]m-1-\jlast.north) -- ([yshift=7.5pt]m-1-\jlast.north east) node [above] {$3$} -- ([xshift=-1.5pt, yshift=-.5pt]m-1-\j.north)
    ;
  \foreach \i [remember=\i as \ilast (initially 1), count=\k from 3] in {2,...,8}
  \draw [thick, draw=magenta!50!blue]
  ([xshift=1.5pt, yshift=.5pt]d\ilast.south) -- ([yshift=-7.5pt]d\ilast.south -| m-1-\k.center) node [below] {$2$} -- ([xshift=-1.5pt, yshift=.5pt]d\i.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: annotated matrix]

Comment: This is exactly the kind of output I wanted, thank you.  It will probably take me a few weeks to understand the code, though. :)

Comment: @mweiss Start with the coverage of the `matrix` library in the Ti*k*Z manual so that you understand the naming. Then it will be easier to see what the rest does.

Answer (score 1):

This is a starting point from which you could build on:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
$\Delta x$ & & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{3} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{3}  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{3} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{3} &   \\  \hline
$x$ & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{0} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{3} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{6} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{9} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{12} \\  \hline
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

It is not, as yet, visually very appealing, but you can play with the idea and refine it, if you think this might be a valid approach for what you are looking for.

Of course, you can also have a row for second differences.